# Static sites with nginx and express.js - Authentification

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, nginx

## My plan

In my app, I want to separate the backend from the frontend. I have multiple static sites with vue.js accessing an api provided by an express server. All static files should be served by nginx.
So for now my nginx config file looks like this:

```
http {
  ...
  upstream backend {
    server localhost:3000;
    keepalive 64;
  }
  ...
  server {
    ...
    location /api {
      ...
      proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
  }
}
```

So all request to `/api` are handled by express running at port `3000`. Users can login through the frontend that is accessing the backend api.

## Now to the **problem**:

I have some sites (e.g. `/dash`) that are also static but should only be accessible for users that are authenticated (authentication is handled by express session) and with a specific user role (e.g. `editor`).
A user who is not an `editor` should get a `error 403` when accessing `/dash` while for the others, `/dash` should be served by nginx.

I hope I was clear enough, it is not easy to express my problem properly. I appreciate any help and advice, maybe my approach is not a good idea or is a bad practice.

## Edit

Solution can be found in comments of the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, authorization to some static files should be handled in the backend-server and not in nginx. Nginx is just a proxy, and not a handler for authorization. Maybe check out [passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport) if you're using express.

Secondly, I think you have the wrong idea about static files. A tip would be to compile them to make them smaller(check out http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html). But that's how far nginx will handle your static files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already implemented authentication and it is handled by express, I used passport.  
Nginx should not render but only serve the files. The files than access the API using ajax. I've wanted to use nginx to serve the files as it is supposed to be faster.
But still I want to restrict access to some certain sites for which I would have to check with a middleware whether the user is allowed. For every other site, everyone is allowed, so only use nginx for those. Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: I believe you should use nginx for your whole site in this matter. The authorization-middleware should make sure the right static files are rendered and served to the user, nginx is just a reflection of your server, and not the actual server

Comment: Ok so just pass the proxy to express?

Comment: Well, you pass your server to the proxy. Check out this video(a bit bad english, but good enough for this purpose): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OuRhaSQljsc

Comment: Thanks, I know how to do this ;) I appreciate the help and advice.

Comment: Okay! This is what I used for my previous nginx-setup: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/thajo/d5db8e679c1237dfdb76/raw/24771c3a136e052c6bca4da909211b1b053dd164/nginx_conf - Maybe it will give some more understanding if there is any unclearity! But yeah, you should just handle the authorization on the backend, and leave nginx to compile static files and offer ssl-requests basically

Comment: Aaaah ok so you serve static files such as images, *.css, *.js etc. with nginx (for performance) and for everything else, you pass the proxy to express? That's perfect!